# Simple socket communication port scanner

Tags: networking, perl

At the moment, `prtscn` takes a server, and a list of port ranges to test (of the form x,y-z,a-c,d,e etc). The `-v` option will show all ports being scanned, and the `-r` option will return the first open port in the list. If `-r` is passed, the list of port ranges is optional. In this case, if the port list is missing, `-r` will just return the first open port on the target OS.

Going forward, the next option I would like to add is a pretty printer for the open ports (IE, if it returns 22, 80, 4200, 4201, 4202, then that should print 22, 80, 4200-4202) and potentially make this async.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# prtscn.pl - scan server for open

# TODO
# Make async
# if any ports are sequential, form a range (ie if 22, 4200, 4201, and 4202 are open, print 22, 4200-4202)

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket;
use Getopt::Long;

my $verbosity = undef;
my $use_first_port = undef;

GetOptions('v' => \$verbosity, 'u' => \$use_first_port);

sub scan {
    my $server = shift;
    my $start_port = shift;
    my $end_port = shift;
    my @open_ports = ();

    while($start_port-1 < $end_port) {
        if($verbosity) {
            print "scanning port $start_port.\n";
        }

        my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerHost => $server, PeerPort => $start_port);

        if($sock) {
            push @open_ports, $start_port;

            if($use_first_port) {
                return @open_ports;
            }
        }

        $start_port += 1;
    }

    return @open_ports;
}

my $server = shift || die "err: need server.\n";
my $range_list = shift || "1-65536";
my @ranges = split /,/, $range_list || die "err: need range list.\n";
my @open_ports = ();

foreach my $range (@ranges) {
    my ($start, $end) = (undef, undef);

    if($range =~ /-/) {
        ($start, $end) = split /-/, $range;
    } else {
        ($start, $end) = ($range, $range);
    }

    push @open_ports, scan($server, $start, $end); 
}

if(scalar @open_ports != 0) {
    print "open port(s): ${\join ', ', sort @open_ports}\n";
} else {
    print "no ports listed are open.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Layout

Place the `scan` sub at the end of the file instead of in the middle of the procedural code.

### `use` as little as possible

I prefer to only import the necessary functions form the modules (in the `use` lines).  Since you are not using anything from `IO::Socket`, you can pass it the empty list: `qw()`.

You only use one function from `Getopt::Long`.

### Variable declarations

There is no need to explicitly initialize variables to `undef` or the empty list in your code.

It is not possible to hit the `die` statement on the `@ranges` line.

### Comments

Remove the unnecessary `TODO` comments.

### Style

`for` is simlper than `foreach`.

Add space between control keywords (`if`, `while`) and the opening paren `(`.

Use single quotes to avoid unnecessary variable interpolation for the `$range_list` default string.

There is no need for `scalar`.

The `\join` code is a little hard to understand.

Use `++` instead of `+= 1`.

### User documentation and argument checking

Add usage documentation with the standard [Pod::Usage](https://perldoc.perl.org/Pod::Usage) module and plain old documentation ([POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod)).  Move argument parsing and checking to it's own sub.  Check the return value of [GetOptions](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long) for enhanced argument checking.

Your question text mentions the `-r` option, but your code uses `-u` instead.

---

Here is new code with the suggestions above:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket   qw();
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage   qw(pod2usage);

my $verbosity;
my $use_first_port;
my $server;
my $range_list;

parse_args();

my @ranges = split /,/, $range_list;
my @open_ports;

for my $range (@ranges) {
    my ($start, $end);

    if ($range =~ /-/) {
        ($start, $end) = split /-/, $range;
    } else {
        ($start, $end) = ($range, $range);
    }

    push @open_ports, scan($server, $start, $end);
}

if (@open_ports) {
    print 'open port(s): ', (join ', ', sort @open_ports), "\n";
} else {
    print "no ports listed are open.\n";
}
exit;

sub scan {
    my $server      = shift;
    my $start_port  = shift;
    my $end_port    = shift;
    my @open_ports;

    while (($start_port - 1) < $end_port) {
        if ($verbosity) {
            print "scanning port $start_port.\n";
        }

        my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerHost => $server, PeerPort => $start_port);

        if ($sock) {
            push @open_ports, $start_port;

            if ($use_first_port) {
                return @open_ports;
            }
        }

        $start_port++;
    }

    return @open_ports;
}

sub parse_args {
    my $help;
    GetOptions(
        'help'  => \$help,
        'v'     => \$verbosity,
        'u'     => \$use_first_port,
    ) or pod2usage();

    $help and pod2usage(-verbose => 2);

    if (@ARGV) {
        $server = shift @ARGV;
        $range_list  = (shift @ARGV) || '1-65536';
    } else {
        pod2usage('Error: server required.');
    }

    @ARGV and pod2usage("Error: unexpected args: @ARGV");
}

=head1 NAME

prtscn

=head1 SYNOPSIS

prtscn [options] server [range]

    Options:
    -help   Verbose help
    -v      Verbose output for debug
    -u      Use first port

=head1 DESCRIPTION

Show ports for a server.

=head1 ARGUMENTS

=over 4

=item B<server>

A server is required.

=item B<range>

A range is optional.  The default range is C<1-65536>

=back

=head1 OPTIONS

All options can be abbreviated.

=over 4

=item B<-v>

Show verbose output on stdout

    prtscn -v 0.0.0.0

=item B<-u>

By default, show all ports in the range.
To show just the first port in the range, use the C<-u> option.

    prtscn -u 0.0.0.0 111-555

=item B<-help>

Show verbose usage information.

=back

=cut
```